# Flyway won't close connection after migrate

Tags: java, flyway

I'm using Flyway in a JSF context with MySQL. Only on startup of the deployment Flyway migrates successfully to the newest version and is never used outside that case. However, the jdbc-connection still persists after the migration.

I've updated Flyway to the currently newest Version 9.12.0 which did not resolve the problem.

```java
public class FlywayMigrateUtil {
    
    private final String SCRIPTS_PATH = "classpath:alter-scripts";
    private final String LOGGER = "log4j2";
    DataSource ds;
    Flyway flyway;
    public FlywayMigrateUtil(DataSource ds){
        setDs(ds);
        setFlyway(configureFlyway());
    }

    public Flyway configureFlyway(){
        FluentConfiguration config = new FluentConfiguration();
        config.dataSource(getDs());
        config.baselineOnMigrate(true);
        config.cleanDisabled(true);
        config.outOfOrder(true);
        config.validateMigrationNaming(true);
        config.validateOnMigrate(false);
        config.locations(SCRIPTS_PATH);
        config.loggers(LOGGER);
        
        return new Flyway(config);
    }
}
```

```java
public class FlywayMigrationHandler {
    
    private final String DATASOURCE_LOOKUP = "java:comp/env";
    private final String SWITCH_LOOKUP = "java:comp/env/AllowFlywayMigration";
    private final String DATA_SOURCE_NAME = "flyway/datasource";
    private Context initialContext;
    private boolean enableFlywayMigration;
    private Context envContext;
    private DataSource ds;
    private FlywayMigrateUtil flywayMigrateUtil;
    
    public FlywayMigrationHandler() throws NamingException {
        
        setInitialContext(new InitialContext());
        setEnableFlywayMigration((boolean) getInitialContext().lookup(SWITCH_LOOKUP));
        
        if(isEnableFlywayMigration()){
            setEnvContext((Context) getInitialContext().lookup(DATASOURCE_LOOKUP));
            setDs((DataSource) getEnvContext().lookup(DATA_SOURCE_NAME));
            setFlywayMigrateUtil(new FlywayMigrateUtil(getDs()));
        }
        
    }

    public void makeMigration(){
        if(getDs() != null && isEnableFlywayMigration()){
            try{
                Flyway flyway = getFlywayMigrateUtil().getFlyway();
                flyway.migrate();

                //close connection?

            }catch (FlywayException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I tell Flyway to close the connection?

Comment: How do you know the connection is not closed? The problem is likely not Flyway itself, but the data source being backed by a connection pool.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel by looking at the current connections in mysql `show processlist;`. There's still a connection with the flyway-user

Comment: Then very likely it is your data-source keeping the connection open in a connection pool. Is this actually a problem, or you were just wondering why?

Comment: At the moment its a problem on a test-environment where multiple deployments are running at the same time for different features and bugfixes.

Comment: Then you should either not use a data source, not use a data source backed by a connection pool, or find a way to shutdown or clear this data source (which may or may not be possible, this will depend on what the provider is of that data source).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A database connection can also be assigned to flyway using **username**, **password** and **url**.
With these parameters the database connection used by flyway will be closed again when all scripts are migrated.

From a DataSource the needed parameters can be read, but that **is different for every implementation of the DataSource** interface which is provided from the environment.

---

The following example assumes that the **DataSource** is from a **Tomcat web server** environment (in Java 17):

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
    <version>10.0.8</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

```java
import org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;

[...]

private Flyway configureFlyway() {
    FluentConfiguration config = new FluentConfiguration();

    if (getDs() instanceof BasicDataSource tomcatBasicDataSource) {
        String username = tomcatBasicDataSource.getUsername();
        String password = tomcatBasicDataSource.getPassword();
        String url = tomcatBasicDataSource.getUrl();
        config.dataSource(url, username, password);
    }

    config.baselineOnMigrate(true);
    config.cleanDisabled(true);
    config.outOfOrder(true);
    config.validateMigrationNaming(true);
    config.validateOnMigrate(false);
    config.locations(SCRIPTS_PATH);
    config.loggers(LOGGER);

    return new Flyway(config);
}
```

---

FYI Flyway configuration can also be set via builder pattern (which is more compact):

```java
return Flyway.configure()
    .dataSource(url, username, password)
    .baselineOnMigrate(true)
    .cleanDisabled(true)
    .outOfOrder(true)
    .validateMigrationNaming(true)
    .validateOnMigrate(false)
    .locations(SCRIPTS_PATH)
    .loggers(LOGGER)
    .load();
```

Comment: Initializing the FluentConfiguration this way, releases the connection after the migrate.
I've adapted the code to Java 11 and Tomcat 9 as it seems to include features from a newer Java version.